# Send HTML email on form submit via Google Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

This is my code. The first part of the code sets the drop down menu to New then it should send an email. The test Function Works but the the actual onFormSubmit and the sendEmail does not work. Any help would be appreciated. This worked formerly a few weeks ago then stopped working.

Current JavaScript Code.

```
// LIVE FORM V

// ONFORMSUBMIT GET INFO FROM SS, FORMAT, AND SEND EMAIL
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log("[METHOD] onFormSubmit");
  
  // SET VALUE OF LAST OPEN CELL TO 'NEW'
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var last = sh.getLastRow();
  sh.getRange(last,1,1).setValues([['NEW']]);
  
}

// SEND EMAIL FUNCTION
function sendEmail(range) {
  Logger.log("[METHOD] sendEmail");
  
  // FETCH SPREADSHEET
  var values = range.getValues();
  var row = values[0];
  
  // EXTRACT VALUES
  var reqEmail = row[1];
  var reqName = row[2];
  var reqPhone = row[3];
  var beginDateTime = row[4];
  var endDateTime = row[5];
  var locOfInc = row[6];
  var desOfInc = row[7];
  var typOfRec = row[8];
  var reasonForReq = row[9];
  
  // PREPARE EMAIL LAYOUT AND RECIPIENTS
  // Email address to add back: 
  var emailRecipients = "Test@test.com";
  var emailSubject = ""+reqName+" is making a request.";
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('emailLayout');
  template.reqEmail = reqEmail;
  template.reqName = reqName;
  template.reqPhone = reqPhone;
  template.beginDateTime = beginDateTime;
  template.endDateTime = endDateTime;
  template.locOfInc = locOfInc;
  template.desOfInc = desOfInc;
  template.typOfRec = typOfRec;
  template.reasonForReq = reasonForReq;
  var emailToSend = template.evaluate().getContent();

  // SEND EMAIL
  MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: emailRecipients,
  subject: emailSubject,
  htmlBody: emailToSend
 });
  
}

/*
// USE THIS TO TEST THE EMAIL FUNCTIONALLITY OF THE FORM

function test() {
  Logger.log("[METHOD] test");
  
  var ssResponses = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Responses");
  var testRange = ssResponses.getRange(2,1,1,ssResponses.getLastColumn());
  sendEmail(testRange);
}
*/
```

This is the HTML email layout I have written.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>
      <a href='Link'> Link to Database</a>
    </h3>
    <strong>Requestor's Email</strong>
    <br /> <?= reqEmail ?>
    <hr />
    <strong>Requestor's Name</strong>
    <br /> <?= reqName ?>
    <hr />
    <strong>Requestor's Phone Number</strong>
    <br /> <?= reqPhone ?>
    <hr />
    <strong>Begining Date & Time</strong>
    <br /> <?= beginDateTime ?>
    <hr />
    <strong>Ending Date & Time</strong>
    <br /> <?= endDateTime ?>
    <hr />
    <strong>Location of Incident</strong>
    <br /> <?= locOfInc ?>
    <hr />
    <strong>Description of Incident</strong>
    <br /> <?= desOfInc ?>
    <hr />
    <strong>Type of Records</strong>
    <br /> <?= typOfRec ?>
    <hr />
    <strong>Reason for Request</strong>
    <br /> <?= reasonForReq ?>
    <hr />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Form Submit triggers have to be manually turned on, did you do that? Also, how is the `sendEmail` function activated?